# Truncating text fields in searchkit

Tags: searchkit

I'm building lists of incoming enquiries/referrals for our services.

Info comes in from a webform, and includes a text field to capture details of reasons for referral/ contact need.

Some of these statements of need can be minor essays, and makes the incoming referral list difficult to use.

Is there a way to truncate the amount of text that appears in the table listing? Say max number of words/ characters?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try {'[Referral_Details.Further_Details]'|truncate} (will limit to default 80 characters) or {'[Referral_Details.Further_Details]'|truncate:30} to set the number of characters.

Comment: That method worked. But then made some entries display blank.

Can't work out what's causing that to happen. Text in the activity record in Civi seems fine- no obvious formatting.

Comment: Removed "truncate" from rewrite settings and entries affected are still showing as blank